# Updating .htaccess rewrite conditions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'll like to update the following rewrite condition to only allow one particular subdomain.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com$ [NC]

At the moment, it matches all subdomains, but I'd like to allow just one - admin.domain.com.  How would I do this?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} admin.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule //whatever
```

Am I wrong?

Comment: It could, but then I'd lose the redirect from www to non-www.  I settled on this: 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

I'll check you as the answer since technically yours should work to fix the admin redirect problem.